# Starting a docker container for Shopware 6

Tags: docker, shopware6

Im following this quickstart guide: https://github.com/shopware/platform#quickstart--installation

Everything worked until I tried to start the docker container via `./psh.phar docker:start` in the cmd. The docker hub starts but no container. Im not getting any errors. Can someone help me?

Comment: `psh.phar` is just a wrapper around the shell scripts. what does
`bash -x dev-ops/docker/actions/start.sh` print? This should show the single commands executed and give you an idea of where it stops.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite an answer to your question, but I & Shopware recommends using https://dockware.io for the "quick start" of any of your docker work. Here is a link from their tutorial: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/installation/dockware

I have used those images extensively & they boot up without much modifications needed.